# Computer Modern Prototype Numbers

Tags: fonts, metafont, computer-modern

When I read *Mathematical Typography*, I noticed that the prototype font presented (the predecessor of the Computer Modern font family) had different numbers (bottom).
[image: Regular CM numbers (top) vs. Prototype CM numbers (bottom)]
My question is, are there any versions of the font available anywhere that still has this number style?